# Datepicker setting a current date into textbox on Input FocusOut

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, bootstrap-datepicker, lost-focus

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0-rc.4/methods.html) plugin in my Asp.net MVC application.

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<input class="form-control formDatePicker" id="Employee_DateOfBirth" name="Employee.DateOfBirth" readonly="readonly" value="22-02-1988 00:00:00" type="text">
```

And Here's my JQuery Code.

```
if ($('.formDatePicker').length > 0) {
    $('.formDatePicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd-mm-yy"
    });
}
```

Here, **datepicker** is working fine except when I click on textbox and do a **focusout** then datepicker will set a **current date** into textbox. How to avoid this?

Comment: Add **onClose** event. For example `onClose:function(input, inst){$(this).html('')}` Write this code inside your datepicker({}) method.

Comment: @BasantaMatia Not working. I tried this in fiddle, It's working fine there but not in my local machine. I think, I'm missing something..

Comment: It should work in your local machine too. Clear your browser cache and reload once.